# What is mID in Android Studio Layout Inspector?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-uiautomator

In Android Studio Layout Inspector, there is a property for "mID".  Is this the same thing as the R ID?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The layout inspector will look at your generated `R` class and attempt to match up the ID resource with its name.